# JSF 2.0 Execute javascript on FacesContext.responseComplete()

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.0, and when a form is submitted, I am generating a download.  As a result of this, the submission is NOT using AJAX.  When the file has been generated for download, I am calling `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();` to tell the browser it's done.

However, for the sake of User Experience, I want to show a "loading" message on screen when the file is being generated, then remove this message once the download has been generated.  Is there a way to do this considering the lack of AJAX?

Thanks,
Chris

**Edit:**
I am already calling the javascript to *show* the message onSubmit.  My problem is then calling the Javascript to remove the message when the response has completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raise your loading message [before submitting the form](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html#onsubmit).

[`FacesContext.responseComplete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29) does not send any response to the client. It merely sets a flag in the context to tell the JSF framework that no further lifecycle phases should be processed after the current one completes.

Comment: Sorry, bad explanation on my part, I'm already calling the required Javascript on the form's onSubmit event.  However I want to then call Javascript to remove it once the response has completed.

Comment: Ah, I should have thought of that.

Comment: There's a cookie-based approach described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download).

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising!